# Unable to remove content from homepage

Tags: theme, cms, magento2.3.1, cms-pages

I'm trying to remove content from my homepage. I have just installed a theme and even if I set a blank page as  a default page (homepage) the content get's added. I tried to figure out if it's a file causing but my experience is to less.

If I create a blank page it stays blank until I set it as CMS Home Pagein the backend.

Where can I find this file causing that and what do I have to delete/edit in order to get that removed?

Comment: You mean to say. You created a blank cms page. And it is run with some contents. RIght?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Add/Remove block using below code. open your theme xml file add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: thanks for helping:(

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the code but it did not work. There is still content on the homepage.

Comment: Nevermind my other comment. It was the storeview that was causing the problem, created a new one and add your code to the xml. Worked. Thank you very much!